Tinkerpop vertex property single cardinality is not working
When creating a vertex i explicitly mentioned Cardinality as single still its taking list, not able figure out why.
wg.addV("label")
.property(VertexProperty.Cardinality.single,"name", "testname").next();

In the above code even after mentioning single it is storing as list.
gremlin server and java driver both use 3.7.2 version.
UPDATE:
Sorry my bad its working got confused by valueMap(true) output where its returning as array for all the fields
g.V(1).valueMap(true).next();

returns
name=[peter], email=[dummy]

So i thought its is storing as list but fixed when used
g.V(1).valueMap(true).by(unfold()).next();

returns
name=peter, email=dummy


I just attempted this in Gremlin Console 3.7.2 with TinkerGraph and it seems to be working as expected:
gremlin> g.addV('test').property(single,'name','John')
==>v[0]
gremlin> g.V(0L).values('name')
==>John
gremlin> g.V(0L).property(single,'name','Jane')
==>v[0]
gremlin> g.V(0L).values('name')
==>Jane

Can you provide further details as to where you're seeing multiple values for the given property?
